# How can I concatenate columns in a INSERT SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I botched a Bulk Insert and need to do an INSERT SELECT into a restructured table. I have something like:

**Columns**

```
PatientName AdmissionNumber PatientNumber ...
```

And a Comma in the patient name during the bulk insert threw off the columns, so I need to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT [PatientName] ', ' [AdmissionNumber] AS PatientName, 
AdmisttionNumber,
...
FROM Table1
```

What is the correct syntax in MSSQL?

Comment: _join_ has a very particular meaning when talking about databases. I think you mean _concatenate_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about concatenation, not joins. To concatenate in SQL Server use the plus  sign (+).

```
...SELECT [PatientName] + ', ' + ....
```

If needed cast column types [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
   INSERT INTO Table2
    SELECT [PatientName] + ', ' + Convert(nvarchar(10),[AdmissionNumber]) AS PatientName, 
    AdmisttionNumber,
...
FROM Table1
```

Thanks
Suresh